# Use Application.OnKey to shade a cell to yellow

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro so if I press F11, it would highlight the cell yellow.

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work when I press F11.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.OnKey "{F11}", "Yellow"

End Sub

Private Sub Yellow()
    With Selection.Interior
        .Color = 65535
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you put the code of the OnKey Action into the module of `ThisWorkbook`, you have to call it like that

```
Application.OnKey "{F11}", "ThisWorkbook.Yellow"
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Sub` to be called must be **in a standard module**. Or it must be called specifying the Sheet/Workbook module name, too.

```
Sub Yellow()
   Selection.Interior.Color = 65535
End Sub
```

Comment: You do not have to cancel the `F11` short cut with `Application.OnKey "{F11}", ""`  first. It will be overwritten. And  `Application.OnKey "{F11}", "Yellow"` will only work if placed in a _normal_ module.

Comment: @Storax: On my installation (Office 2016 Proffesional Plus) it insers a Chart sheet... I edited and specify (in a standard module) before you menioned that. I thought that it is self understood...

Comment: Yes, that is the normal function. But as soon as you call `Application.OnKey "{F11}", "Yellow"` the normal function will be overwritten. No need to call `Application.OnKey "{F11}", ""` first.